# Importing xml files with an encoder element at the start(using lxml)

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I have a file `trace.xml`.The very first line in this file is`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.I tried reading the data using the following command:

```
with open('trace.xml') as fobj:
xml=fobj.read()
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

This however yields the following error:`ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`
I am assuming its because of the very first tag i mentioned above.Is there a way around this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

to

```
root = etree.fromstring(xml.encode())
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much it did the job